# Why is my Material UI theme not imported or applying the styles?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to customize my styles using MUI createTheme but it's not getting imported. By my understanding, my toolbar should be light blue, but it's dark blue. I'm using React v17.0.2 with MUI v4.12.3, maybe the versions don't match ? I'm not sure what the issue is, check my code out and lemme know, thanks a ton !!

```
// Theme.js

import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const arcBlue = '#0B72B9'
const arcOrange = '#FFBA60'

export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    common: {
      blue: `${arcBlue}`,
      orange: `${arcOrange}`,
    },
    primary: {
      main: `${arcBlue}`,
    },
    secondary: {
      main: `${arcOrange}`,
    },
  },
})
```

```
// Header.js

import React from 'react'
import { AppBar, Toolbar, useScrollTrigger } from '@material-ui/core'

function ElevationScroll(props) {
  const { children } = props

  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
    disableHysteresis: true,
    // avoiding the delay when you first scroll

    threshold: 100,
    // when to take effect, at 0 means immediately, higher up - later then
  })

  return React.cloneElement(children, {
    elevation: trigger ? 4 : 0,
  })
}

const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <ElevationScroll>
      <AppBar position='fixed'>
        <Toolbar>Arc Development</Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </ElevationScroll>
  )
}

export default Header
```

```
// App.js

import React from 'react'
import Header from './ui/Header'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles'
import { theme } from './ui/Theme'

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Header />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

[Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVLGY.png)

Comment: There isn`t any problem based on your, check it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-hooks-kl9rw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yeah so why isn't it working for me ? You can see the color differences in my toolbar and yours, but the code is the same. So why is that ?

Comment: Have you tried ctrl + f5 to clear cache?

Comment: I just tried it when I saw your message, but it didn't change the result. So if the code isn't the issue, where else can I look to solve the issue ?

Comment: Could you provide your code in codesandbox to check?

Comment: It works fine in codesandbox, maybe there's some issue with my code editor